# Using if-else within for loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement

```
marks = [10, 20, 70, 81, 14, 78, 5, 95]
for i in marks:
    if i < 40:
        print('You have failed and secured {} marks'.format (i))
else:
    print("You passed with {} marks".format (i))


OUTPUT::
You have failed and secured 10 marks
You have failed and secured 20 marks
You have failed and secured 14 marks
You have failed and secured 5 marks
You passed with 95 marks
```

How to use else within for loop as it is executed after for loop?

Comment: Your issue is identical to the marked duplicate.. the `else` is being attached to the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is indented incorrectly it should be like this:

```
marks = [10, 20, 70, 81, 14, 78, 5, 95]
for i in marks:
    if i < 40:
        print('You have failed and secured {} marks'.format (i))
    else:
        print("You passed with {} marks".format (i))
```

Python is not using curly brackets so indentation is crucial.

Comment: its output is 
  File "C:/Users/Mukesh/PycharmProjects/mukii/venv/Scripts/ok.py", line 5
    else:
        ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: @MukeshNarwal is that the output of your or my code?

Comment: @MukeshNarwal You have used tabs (i can see from edit mode), Tobias is using 4 spaces (the preferred indentation)- anyway you can't mix them. Also the reason your loop didn't raise an exceptionl before is you discovered python has a `for-else` construct! http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/break_else.html

Comment: @tobias Your code

Comment: @tobias your code is running fine, i copy paste your code and its giving right output thanks.

Comment: @MukeshNarwal Glad, I could help. Feel free to accept my answer for reputation sake.

Comment: @TobiasWilfert Done :)

Answer (score 1):

looks indentation is not proper, following should work

```
for i in marks:
   if i < 40:
       print('You have failed and secured {} marks'.format (i))
   else:
       print("You passed with {} marks".format (i))
```